# Стоит ли использовать alphine.js в react проекте?

Tags: reactjs, tailwindcss, alpine.js

Изначально следил за [уроком по tailwind](https://youtu.be/ANbJ0MZxR-g) и там для выпадающего меню использовался alphine.js  Я, в свою очередь, следую уроку со своими дополнениями, пишу проект на реакте, используя tailwind-styled компоненты и задумался о целесообразности использовать alpinejs в связке с реакт. По теме встретился еще такой [туториал](https://codewithhugo.com/alpine-js-react/), но не покидает ощущение, что это какая-то необязательная сущность и костыль.

Comment: ощущения совпадают)

Comment: При том что уже используется реакт, подключать аналогичную ему (по сути) библиотеку не нужно. Да и общем, alpine.js на данный момент имеет нерешенные проблемы кроссбраузерности, плюс это пет-проект... пока что не советую в прод, даже без реакта. Короче, если чем-то понравился элпайн, то просто возьми вместо реакта вью и не парься - все три библиотеки это практически одно и то же (alpine.js просто сильнее зависит от разметки, чем реакт и вью)... более того: элпайн непосредственно использует кусок вью (vue-reactivity) как свое "ядро", автор просто поменял обвязку и префикс директив :)

Comment: Alpine.js это решение когда надо быстро (из-за экстренности задачи, или просто нежелания тратить на нее время) слепить "абы что", "лишь бы хоть как-то работало". Библиотека прекрасно походит для сайтов под внутреннее/личное пользование, для непопулярных стартапов в начале пути, или для MVP-вебмордочки (как временное решение пока не готова стабильная прод версия). Но не более того. Если делаешь что-то в паблик доступ (и уж тем более если проект коммерческий) и при том хочешь стабильности - то держись за реакт/вью, не соблазняйся модными новинками, которые еще толком не обкатаны...